# Remove Ubuntu and grow Mac partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, unix

I'm new to the whole Mac world, and the first thing I did when I got my MacBook Air 2015 was I installed Ubuntu, but have regretted it now and want to remove it and get my space back into the Mac partition.

I have tried to do it with Disk Utility in OS X, but it just fails and it's not giving any real error code. So I don't know how I can do it?

This is how my partitions looks:

[image]

---

**Update**

From Recovery Mode:

[image]

```
-bash-3.2# sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.10.5
BuildVersion:   14F27
```

Comment: I got into some big problems. I tried to remove 'what I thought was' the Linux Swap partition in Disk Utility on osx and had no success (before I asked this question), and now when I booted back to osx I got this error: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156 the "Prohibitory symbol"
So I think I'm just gonna drop all and completely reinstall osx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Booted to Internet Recovery Mode you have to remove all non-OS X partitions, modify the partition types of your macOS partitions (but keep their sizes!) and then resize your main volume. The reason why you can't boot your Mac is the bogus partition type (FFFF-FFF....) of your main partition (i=2/sda2). Additionally the Recovery HD partition (i=3/sda3) has the wrong type.

**Preparation:**

- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.

  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan). If you boot to a full system and login as admin you have to prepend `sudo` to execute some commands like `gpt ...` or `newfs_hfs ...`!

**Remove the Linux Swap and main partition**

- Open in the menubar Utlities->Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` to get an overview
- Remove the Linux partitions:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt remove -i 4 /dev/disk0
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt remove -i 5 /dev/disk0
  ```

**Modify the OS X partitions (LVG)**

Your main partition may either have the type 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (CoreStorage) or 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC (classical OS X partition). Usually SSD and filevaulted partitions use CoreStorage meanwhile.

- First try the CoreStorage type

  ```
  gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0 
  gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 118430560 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  diskutil cs list
  ```

  Check if you have a CoreStorage LVG. If not, continue with **Modify the OS X partitions (Standard)**. If you have found an LVG, continue with:

  ```
  diskutil list
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/diskX #check for a disk identifier of a volume with the size ~60 GB and replace X with the number of that disk (it may be 2, 3 or ~13)
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 118840200 -i 3 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk0
  diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2
  ```

**Resize OS X partition**

- Enter `diskutil list` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk0` again. If you have a CoreStorage LVG your partition listing and the partition map should look like this now:

  ```
  diskutil list
  /dev/disk0
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
     2:          Apple_CoreStorage                          60.6 GB   disk0s2
     3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
  /dev/disk1 Base OS X System
  ....
  /dev/disk2 #this may also have another disk identifier like disk13 or disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                      SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD               60.0 GB    disk2
  /dev/disk3-disk12 or 13 a lot of small sized disks (512 kb - 8 MB) which are part of the Recovery System

  gpt -r show disk0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   118430560      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   118840200     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   120109736   116868407         
   236978143          32         Sec GPT table
   236978175           1         Sec GPT header
  ```
- Now enter `diskutil cs list`

  You should get a list with 4 UUIDs of the various items of the CoreStorage LVG.
- Resize the whole stack to the full size:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID 0g
  ```

  with lvUUID: UUID of the Logical Volume. It's the last one listed and looks similar to this: 9A7B21AA-F9FE-4E65-8C7E-ED2A73744C15. 0g is a magical size which expands an LV and the superior LVG to the max available size

  In your case it's the one starting with 10F16... so your final command is

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack 10F16........ 0g
  ```

  If your main volume is encrypted you have to unlock it first and enter the  password of your user on the main volume or another proper passphrase.

  ```
  diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID
  ```

  In your case it's the one starting with 10F16... so your final command is

  ```
  diskutil cs unlockVolume 10F16........
  ```

  After successfully expanding your Logical Volume quit Terminal by entering `exit` and <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> and reboot to your main volume.

**Modify the OS X partitions (Standard)**

- remove the CoreStorage partition and re-add it as standard partition:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 118430560 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt add -b 118840200 -i 3 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
  diskutil verifyDisk /dev/disk0
  diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2
  ```
- Expand the main partition disk0s2 with the common tools (Disk Utility or diskutil)

Comment: Thanks and it works!, just one problem. When I rebooted I got into gnu grub, I just wrote `exit` and it successfully booted into osx and I had all my space back! :D but seems like always when booting it's going to grub first and then I have to write `exit` every time on boot

Comment: @Jeggy You probably installed grub somewhere (EFI or MBR) hmm. That's probably a second question.

Comment: @Jeggy Do you remember where you installed grub? Some internet resources say `fdisk -u /dev/disk0` in Internet Recovery Mode if grub is installed to the MBR - but back up your machine first with Time Machine ;-)

Answer (score -2):

with just updating the version of osx , u can grow the partition size.... for this delete the ubuntu partition(which then cant be merged with the existing macintosh partition) and then update the version of osx followed by merging.. this time it will merge,,

Comment: this way it worked for me. coz when i was trying to expand mac partition after removing ubuntu, it was prompting with an error and the space which was previously being used by ubuntu was left as free and unusable. ... the reason for it has to do with core storage logical volume groups in the partitions... which subsided with the upgrade of mac os x... and then system could expand the size of mac partition with existing unused previously occupied ubuntu free space..