# Remove Linux partition on Mac. CoreStorage problems

Tags: macbook-pro, partition, core-storage

I have a Macbook pro 2015 with a 256 GB SSD and a Linux partition. I would like to remove the partition. Following the steps written in [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225532/93229), I got stuck in the Modify step. Once I execute the command `gpt add -b 409649 ...` and than I do the diskutil list command, it does not appear any disk with the size 60 GB.

[image: output of terminal 1:]

[image: gpt -r show disk0:]

Does any one know how to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes!!! I have my Mac back again! Thank you! You are the best!!

Comment: I either write a short answer or mark this question a duplicate of a q&a already answered (when I can find a q&a)

Answer (score 2):

By accident the OP took one command in the answer [Remove Ubuntu and grow Mac partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225532/93229) literally and entered:

```
gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 118430560 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
```

to add a partition table entry, though his original macOS volume was much larger. The command above creates a ~60 GB CoreStorage partition right after the EFI partition.
No output of the previous partition table was available `(sudo) gpt -r show diskX`.

To recreate the partition table an external volume with a full macOS install, wxHexEditor and some knowledge about the typical sizes and internal structures of macOS recovery volumes is necessary.

- Install macOS to a thumb drive and configure it.
- Download and install [wxHexEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxhexeditor/)
- Search for the typical start blocks of the Recovery HD like in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/176909/93229) answer.
- Recreate the Recovery HD with `gpt add -i 3 ...`
- Recreate the main macOS volume between EFI and Recovery HD partition `gpt add -i 2 ...`
- Verify the disk and the volumes with `diskutil verify[Disk|Volume] diskYsX`
- Expand the recovered main volume