# Unbootable mac and need to recover data

Tags: mac

Today i deleted from disk utility a linux partition (dual boot) on my macbook and i get an failure. Then i restarted but it won't boot..
I don't know what I have to do..
I don't have any recent backup but i need to recover some data from the SSD and I don't know how to do this.. Please help me

[image: diskUtil list and gpt -r show disk0]

EDIT: I need to recover files from MacOS partition, I don’t care anymore of Linux partition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Linux partition on Mac. CoreStorage problems](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281869/remove-linux-partition-on-mac-corestorage-problems)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to visit a data recovery center and have them inspect the hard drive and see if they can find and copy any data from the Linux partition if it hasn't been formatted.

Comment: Sorry but i don’t need to recover files from Linux partition. I need to take files from MacOS partition.

Comment: Ok, they would also be recommended for taking files from the Mac partition if it can still be read. It's likely that the hard drive needs to be formatted for use again or replaced. Unless you can see it in MacOS Recovery via Disk Utility there.

Comment: Ok thank you, there’s nothing I can do at home now..? I read that other people were able to recover files with terminal commands or other methods..

Comment: That can be done, but I would let a professional do it, that'll way they are  able to do the most for you and then if they damage anything they are liable.

Comment: At the end I solved the problem creating a disk image on my external HDD and opening it on another Mac, initialized my macbook and copy-pasted all important stuff. However thank you so much for the help! :D