# Why I can't remove linux partitions on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, disk-format

I'm trying to **remove linux partition** from my iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) on MacOS Sierra 10.12 Beta 2, So I tried existing solutions by **using Disk Utility**, I tried from Recovery as well, But it says

> You can not remove this volume because the previous volume can not be resized

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some [existing solutions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225532/242369) use Terminal but I have no idea about that.

**I need a simplest and easiest way to remove these linux partitions and grow my mac partition.**

Comment: You can't (grow-)resize a partition (here the macOS partition disk0s5) to lower block numbers with macOS tools. Therefore a solution is even more complex than the linked one. Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0` entered in Terminal to your question!

Comment: @klanomath Here is the [screenshot](http://imgur.com/hutUB6I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't expand a macOS partition to lower block numbers (i.e. to the "beginning of a disk") with on-board macOS tools.

Basically you have to remove all useless partitions, clone or restore your main macOS drive to a new partition on the same drive and delete the old one.

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive).
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either Ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.
- Verify and repair your main macOS volume with Disk Utility

**Modify partition table:**

- Open in the menubar Utilities/Terminal

  First you should get an overview of your disks and the partition layout:
- Enter `diskutil list`
  Example listing:

  ```
  /dev/disk0
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        500.1 GB    disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                    209.7 MB    disk0s1
     2:           Linux Filesystem                        499.1 MB    disk0s2
     3:                 Linux Swap                          2.0 GB    disk0s3
     4:           Linux Filesystem                        247.5 GB    disk0s4
     5:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X               248.6 GB    disk0s5
     6:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD            650.0 MB    disk0s6
     7:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD            650.0 MB    disk0s7
  /dev/disk1
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:     Apple_partition_scheme                         *1.3 GB    disk1
     1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk1s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        *1.3 GB    disk1s2
  /dev/disk2-~disk14...
  ```

  /dev/disk1-~disk14 ...belong to the macOS Base System (your recovery system you booted to previously)

  disk0 is your main internal disk device containing the EFI-partition (dis0s1), some Linux partitions (disk0s2-disk0s4), your main macOS volume (disk0s5) and two Recovery HDs (disk0s6/disk0s7) one of which is useless - probably disk0s7.
- To get a standard partition layout you have to delete a lot of partitions, create a new partition, dd or asr your main macOS volume to a new one and rearrange your recovery partition:
- Get an overview:

  ```
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- Remove partitions (which requires to unmount disk0)

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 7 disk0 #remove 2nd recovery partition
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 4 disk0 #remove Linux 2nd partition (main)
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 3 disk0 #remove Linux Swap
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 2 disk0 #remove Linux 1st partition (booter?)
  ```
- Create a new partition for a new main macOS with the same size as your old one:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 408640 -s 485511600 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- Get a new updated view of the partition table:

  ```
  diskutil list
  ```

  Example listing:

  ```
  /dev/disk0
     #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
     0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        500.1 GB    disk0
     1:                        EFI EFI                    209.7 MB    disk0s1
     2:                  Apple_HFS                        248.6 GB    disk0s2
     5:                  Apple_HFS Mac OS X               248.6 GB    disk0s5
     6:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD            650.0 MB    disk0s6
  ```
- dd your "old" macOS partition disk0s5 to the new partition disk0s2:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  dd if=/dev/disk0s5 of=/dev/disk0s2 bs=1m
  ```

  (use the proper disk identifiers here: disk0s5 may be different)
- remove your old main macOS partition

  ```
  gpt -r show disk0
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 5 disk0 #use the proper index number of your old macOS partition here
  ```
- Create a new partition and clone your recovery partition:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt add -i 3 -b 485920240 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  diskutil list #to get the proper device identifiers
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  dd if=/dev/disk0s6 of=/dev/disk0s3 bs=1m
  gpt -r show disk0
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 6 disk0 #use the proper index number of your old recovery partition here
  ```
- Expand your new main volume:

  ```
  diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s2
  diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s2 #if necessary
  diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 499g
  ```
- Reboot to your main volume

**Always make certain to use the proper device identifiers - either with `diskutil list` or `gpt -r show disk0`!**

---

**Finally I recommend to download and install a proper system! Your current system seems to be some public beta of Sierra.**

Comment: Thanks. @klanomath Will my data on "disk0s5" be deleted?

Comment: @RashMendis the step `dd if=/dev/disk0s5 of=/dev/disk0s2 bs=1m` makes a copy of your current disk0s5 to disk0s2. Afterwards disk0s5 will be deleted...and disk0s2 is your new OS X with all your previous data.

Comment: Thanks @klanomath again for the quick response. I'll try and let you know.

Comment: I'm in step `dd your "old" macOS partition disk0s5 to the new partition disk0s2:` now its more than 5 hours but still it processing. **Do you have any idea of duration?**

Comment: But now it's 7.5 hours 

Comment: Can't hear. But not sure since this is a iMac

Comment: Yes it worked! It took 17hrs. Thanks @klanomath

Comment: @RashMendis 17 hours means an average combined r/w speed of 8.2 MB/s. That's really slow...