# Why I'm getting "macOS can't repair the disk"

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, partition

I'm using Macbook Pro Mid 2012 on Sierra. It has two partitions without OS partition. Four times those 2 partitions getting corrupted(can't copy files). And I tried to repair disk, And got this message

[image]

After I restart my MBP got this.

[image]

So as they said I copied the data and reformat it to "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)". Again in 2 days one partition got corrupted. So then I realize File system was "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" and now it shows only "Mac OS Extended".

[image]

```
Rashs-MacBook-Pro:~ rashmendis$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
Password:
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   781975184      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   782384824     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   783654360   715947032      4  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1499601392      262144         
  1499863536   453399448      5  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1953262984      262151         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header

Rashs-MacBook-Pro:~ rashmendis$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage MacOS                   400.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Backup                  366.6 GB   disk0s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Data                    232.1 GB   disk0s5

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            MacOS                  +400.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 6E77AA56-7B2E-4388-9640-F34D7E92164C
                                 Unencrypted
```

Issues having with `disk0s4 and disk0s5`.

**I need to know is this a problem of my HDD drive or a issue with the OS.**

Comment: Please give us more data as to how these got corrupted. Has there been any physical damage?

Comment: No some times MBP stucked. And sometimes it stuck when Time Machine backup preparing Then I restart by pressing Power Button. Then it got corrupted. Again when Time Machine backuping I restarted. Those two are the known instances.

Comment: hmmm this is pretty puzzling. Have you tried running first aid from recovery?

Comment: Yes that also same

Comment: Answer is here! https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287973/242369

Comment: How does this answer the question?